# Breeze js client-side camelCase extension property not mapped from PascalCase server property

Tags: javascript, breeze, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

I'm using Breeze JS to create a client-side extension property as per: http://www.breezejs.com/documentation/extending-entities

My constructor declares two camelCase properties:

```
function Building() {
    this.fullAddress = "";
    this.street = "";
}
```

I register the constructor with my metadata store as follows:

```
store.registerEntityTypeCtor("Building", Building);
```

I am using the camelCase naming convenvention as per: http://www.breezejs.com/documentation/naming-convention

When my Web API returns PascalCase FullAddress and Street properties, my Building entities fail to have their properties set correctly. It only works if I modify the constructor to declare client-side properties in PascalCase also.

It is my understanding that the naming convention should automatically map PascalCase server-side property names to client-side camelCase property names. Could someone please clarify this behaviour? All the other properties for my Building entity (which are not extension properties) are correctly mapped from PascalCase to camelCase.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that we changed the behavior of breeze in 1.4.14 to pass unmapped properties thru the namingConvention converter, previously we did not do this.  Could you try your code on 1.4.14.

Comment: Thanks Jay. An update to Breeze 1.4.14 solved this issue. Order has been restored!

Answer (score 0):

On the page you are referencing it explains why -

> The isBeingEdited property is only a property on the client-side
>   Customer entity. The "Customer" class on the server does not have an
>   isBeingEdited property and the backing database does not have an
>   isBeingEdited column in the "Customer" table either.

In your case your constructor contains properties that Breeze considers to be unmapped.  The reason it works when you switch to PascalCase is a thing called chance : ) and is bad practice.

If your properties are indeed server side and you want to keep them that way then just consider renaming the properties in your constructor to match what comes back from the server.

Comment: Thanks. These are indeed server-side properties, which are returned from my Web API. It just feels such a shame to rename the properties in the constructor to PascalCase, when the other properties on the entity are in camelCase.